# Spring Batch: Non-resolvable parent POM error

Tags: spring, spring-batch, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to import Spring Batch Samples.  I've added all the Maven groupids/artifacts/version as stated on the Spring Web site... But I can't get the project to build.  I've searched Jarfinder trying to find all the imports but still have this problem with the POM.  since it was generated for me when I add Maven, I'm don't know what to do.  Thanks.

I get the error:

Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.springframework.batch:org.springframework.batch.parent:2.0.0.RELEASE in repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in local repository,resolution will not be attempted until updates are forced and 'parent.relative.PATH' points at wrong POM.

I am using SpringSource Toolsuite.

This is the code that's displays the error.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.batch.parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>../spring-batch-parent</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: could you just try after removing <relativePath>??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `artifactId` `org.springframework.batch.parent` is wrong, and should be replaced with `spring-batch-parent` (see maven repository, for example: http://search.maven.org/#browse|301637886)

Comment: that got seems to solve that error, then 50 more showed up.  Is Spring Batch a current product worth using?  Or is it something generally deprecated.  I've tried to install it, track down all the discrepancies, enter version numbers and artifacts from SpringFramework site, but it just seems to be a circular mess? We can really use these features, and I'd like to get these samples working--rather than it be just a bunch of code snipppets.  Any advice or more thorough installation instructions?  Thank you